# Get a list of all members in specific server automatically

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py, discord.net

Is it possible to get a list of all the members ( users ) in a specific server without having a bot on that server? I know it's possible to do this with a bot; you invite a bot to the wanted server, but I want to do it on a server where I don't have any bot. Obviously, I could just get all of them manually but it would take ages.

EDIT: I'm in the server ( with my account ), I just can't add a bot in it because it's not mine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

no you are not able to do that, as the only way you can gain access to a servers member list is by being in that server.

if you are in the server you can do this

```py
mem_list = []
for member in guild:
     mem_list.append(member.id)
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear! I'm not necessarily talking about a way with a bot, it could work without a bot

Comment: nope. still no way to do it. You can use Oauth but it only goes as far as gaining access to that users guilds.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Also no (quick) way to do it if I'm in the server?

Comment: edited my answer to show you how to do so."quick"

Comment: I also edited my post because it wasn't clear enough  I'm in the server, but I don't have any bot in it

Comment: oh haha. no you can only do it with a bot.

Comment: There is a chrome extension for this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dtools-member-list-saver/delmpfioapnibhcbepefgjofgdlifbdh . Another way is to selfbot but that it against discord ToS

Comment: Thanks! How would selfbot that?